# Drawing an image in C#

Tags: c#, bitmap, system.drawing

Baiscally, I'm trying to draw an image, with a big number (my iteration variable's current value) on it:

```
var imageList = new List<Image>();

for (int i = 1; i <= totalCount; i++)    
{
    using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(800,2000))
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        g.DrawString(i.ToString(), 
                     new Font("Arial", 40), 
                     Brushes.Black, 
                     new PointF(400,1000));   
    }
    imageList.Add(bmp);
}
```

But I get an error when reading from this image list: *Parameter is not valid.* What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How do you read from it? Could it be a problem, that you read an Image and not a Bitmap?

Comment: If you are getting an error when *reading* from the list, why do you show us code that *writes* to the list?

Comment: At what piece of code do you get the error? And see @Dervall's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bitmap is going to be destroyed by the `using` scope before it's put into your list. Remove the `using`.

`using` will call `Dispose` on your image, which will invalidate the object. So, when you put it in the `List` you're putting in a dead object.

```
List<Image> imageList = new List<Image>();
for (int i = 1; i <= totalCount; i++)    
{
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(800,2000))
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            g.DrawString(i.ToString(), new Font("Arial", 40), Brushes.Black, new PointF(400,1000));   
        }

        imageList.Add(bmp);
}
```